# Modifying selection algorithm to select weighted items

Tags: algorithm, optimization, select

I am attempting to modify the selection algorithm to work with the following situation:

My imput is a list of numbers x1, x2, ... , xn (not necessarily ordered).

Each of these numbers has a weight "w". I call W the sum of all the weights.

If I provide a value X, which is greater than 0 but no larger than W, how can I find a xi, such that the sum of the weights of all x's with index greater than i is less than X, and xi's weight + sum of the weights of all items with index greater than i is greater than or equal to X.

This is easily accomplished if we sort all the x's according to their index, but I wish to do that without sorting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not have to sort them if you are given the identifier i. It sounds like you want them in order of their identifiers, which are known, so you just have to make one pass through the list O(n) to put them in order. Then follow one of the posted solutions to figure out the proper value of i. Am I misunderstanding the problem?

**Update**

So lets say you have four values, the identifiers are like this:

```
[ x4, x1, x3, x2 ]
```

And their weights respectively are:

```
[ 14, 10, 5, 19 ]
```

All you have to do is first get the lists in order. It is not the same as sorting it because in this cause you have x1 .. xn, where the numbers are all contiguous with no repeats etc. So you know the result will be a new list of size 4.

Make one pass through the first list. In this case the first number has an identifier of 4, so put that in the new list at position 4, and put the first weight in a new weight list also at position 4. Next will be put in position 1, so on and so fourth.

After this one pass, your lists will look like:

```
[ x1, x2, x3, x4 ] and [ 10, 19, 5, 14]
```

So you now have the order you want. It becomes easy at this point to just start at the end of the weight list and find the property you are looking for with at most one more traversal of the list.

Thus it should be O(n).

Comment: People are not ordered by identifier. For example, the identifier could be ordered 3, 2, 1, 4, etc. The weights are also distributed among these items arbitrarily.

Comment: But I assume the identifier is tied to an account? If you want them in order of the identifier... and you know the identifiers (even if they aren't in order yet) it is not a sorting problem assuming they are all continuous etc. You just have to make one pass through to arrange them. Eg. for 3,2,1,4 just make 4 slots and then put each number in it's slot.

Comment: Here is an attempt to rewrite the problem using literals (I guess it's easier to understand it this way):


My imput is a list of numbers x1, x2, ... , xn (not necessarily ordered) and each of these numbers has a weight "w". I call W teh sum of all the weights. 
If I provide a value X, which is greater than 0 but no larger than W, how can I find a xi, such that the sum of the weights of all x's with index greater than i is less than X, and the sum of xi's weight + sum of the weights of all items with index greater than i is greater than or equal to X. 
I'm not sure if your solution is O(n).

Comment: @ghills: Your explanation makes a lot of sense. Although it does not involve using recursive selection to eliminate some of the items at each iteration and that way running in O(n) (what I had in mind initially), I believe it will work a bit better than what I currently have. Thanks for looking at the problem ;)

Comment: @AlexTex no problem. If this answer worked out for you be sure to mark it as correct.